# Export part of Word document to separate MS Excel cells VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to export a Word document sentences in separate EXCEL cells. Basicaly i want to separate different part of WORD document through a specific separator (any) and import the separated sentences in separate cells of EXCEL.

```
Sub TheBoldAndTheExcelful()
Dim docCur  As Document
Dim snt     As Word.Range
Dim i       As Integer
Dim j       As Integer
Set snt = ActiveDocument.Range
'Requires a reference to the 'Microsoft Excel XX.0 Object Library'
Dim appXL As Excel.Application, xlWB As Excel.Workbook, xlWS As Excel.Worksheet

'This assumes excel is currently closed
Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appXL.Visible = True
Set xlWB = appXL.Workbooks.Add
Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets(1)
j = 1
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set docCur = ActiveDocument.Range

For Each snt In docCur.Sentences
    With snt.Find
        .Text = "Technical Indicators and Signals"

        While .Execute
            j = j + 1
            xlWS.Cells(j, i).Value = snt.Text
        Wend
    End With
Next snt

ExitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set snt = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

> Type Mismatch Error

is encountered while executing the above code.

Comment: in which line you get an error??

Comment: I think I can see it... it is in line `Set docCur = ActiveDocument.Range`. Your variable is `Document` type. Try to remove `.Range` in that line.

Comment: There are more errors.
Change `Set docCur = ActiveDocument.Range` to  `Set docCur = ActiveDocument` as suggested, but also change `Dim snt  As Word.Range` to `Dim snt As Sentences` and `For Each snt In docCur.Sentences` to `For Each snt In docCur.Range.Sentences`

Comment: After the changes you have suggested, a new error has been encoutered "Compile Error. method or Data member not found"

 With snt.Find
   .Text = "Technical Indicators and Signals"